# Optimize For in CTE or Subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization, common-table-expression

**Setup:**

I'm experimenting with the `OPTIMIZE FOR` clause in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I've put the following at the end of my query.

```
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@UserType= 'M', @Date UNKNOWN))
```

**Issue:**

However, I'm getting the below error.

```
The variable "@UserType" is specified in the OPTIMIZE FOR clause, but is not used in the query.
```

This variable is used in a subquery within the query, and is only used in that location.

If I try moving the `OPTIMIZE FOR` into the subquery, the stored proc does not compile.  Likewise, I cannot put the subquery in a CTE and optimize within that; that doesn't compile either.

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.
```

**Question:**

Is there any way I can use an `OPTIMIZE FOR` clause within a CTE or subquery?  I'd prefer to use a CTE since they are generally cleaner and more legible.

Answer (score 2):

The `option` keyword must always be placed at the end of the outer most select query.

For example:

```
declare @var int = 1;

with cte
as (
    select @var as val
)
select * from cte
option (optimize for (@var = 2))
```

Comment: From the question: "I've put the following at the end of my query...However, I'm getting the below error."

Comment: Maybe you could post the SQL you're trying to run then.